# How to delete a specific object in an array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

My DB looks like this:

```
_id: 5dd9c43a986f8900178bc588
team: Object
   project:"5dd6cfb4bc97c65a8759a1d4"
   team: Array

    0: Object
       name: "Test User 0"
       role: "Project Lead"

    1: Object
       name: "Test User 1"
       role: "Secretary"

    2: Object
       name: "Test User 2"
       role: "Engineer"
```

I want to delete users dynamically, depending on the user selected on the frontend. Let's say I want to delete only the object that has name "Test User 1" from the DB... I am trying this:

```
  collection_of_projects.updateOne(
            {'_id': ObjectId(team_db_id)}, 
            { $pull: { "team.team.$.name" : {  'name' : team_mate.name }  } },
        false,
        true 
        )
```

where `team_db_id` is the Object ID in the DB but I am getting this error:

`MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.`

It appears it cannot find the element I am searching for, but what am I missing? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query at `{ $pull: { "team.team.$.name" : {  'name' : team_mate.name }  } }` is not correct, You have nested `team` multiple times and in the matching part i.e `team_mate.name` is also not correct. I have tried on the below collection `deleteSubDocs` and it is working fine with the `$pull` operator as:

```
db.deleteSubDocs.update( {_id:ObjectId("5dd9f0670a65bccf463b36ec")}, {$pull: {"team": {"name": "test1"}  }  })
```

For details about the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-all-items-that-match-a-specified-pull-condition) go through the examples in the official documentation and you will automatically figure out what is the issue in your query.

Details of my finding and execution of queries are as belows:

```
> db.deleteSubDocs.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd9f0670a65bccf463b36ec"),
    "team" : [
        {
            "name" : "KP",
            "role" : "Admin"
        },
        {
            "name" : "test1",
            "role" : "role1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "test2",
            "role" : "role 2"
        }
    ]
}
> 
> db.deleteSubDocs.update( {_id:ObjectId("5dd9f0670a65bccf463b36ec")}, {$pull: {"team": {"name": "test1"}  }  })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.deleteSubDocs.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd9f0670a65bccf463b36ec"),
    "team" : [
        {
            "name" : "KP",
            "role" : "Admin"
        },
        {
            "name" : "test2",
            "role" : "role 2"
        }
    ]
}
>
```

It successfully removes the team array value which matches the `name` equal to `test1`, even you can make multiple and query inside this.

Answer (score -1):

UpdateOne() is for updating records. You probably want to use remove().

```
collection_of_projects.remove(
            {'_id': ObjectId(id_of_team_member)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I think removeOne()  *(remove() is deprecated)* will delete the entire document though. I want to keep the parent object, but only delete an object in the array.

Comment: This will delete the entire record.